# Print text at end of semicolon Sed/awk

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I've this strings in a file that looks like `aaaaa;bbbbbbb;ccccc\n` and `aaaaa;bbbbbb\n` the idea is only to show the text between the last semicolon and newline. Output will be

```
ccccc
bbbbb
```

etc.

Thought that I could do it with `sed -e [:]$ | awk -F '\n' {print $1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete everything up to the last semicolon:

```
sed 's/.*;//'
```

Comment: thats actually much easier. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to solve the task:

```
sed 's/.*;//'
awk -F';' '{print $NF}'
rev | cut -d';' -f 1 | rev
```